# Values disappear in dataframe multiindex after set_index()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like that:

```
     scn                cl_name  lqd_mp  lqd_wp  gas_mp  gas_wp  res_mp  res_wp
12    C6                Hexanes   3.398   1.723   2.200   5.835   2.614   2.775
13   NaN       Me-Cyclo-pentane   1.193   0.591   0.439   1.146   0.707   0.733
14   NaN                Benzene   0.037   0.017   0.013   0.030   0.021   0.020
15   NaN           Cyclo-hexane   1.393   0.690   0.697   1.820   0.944   0.979
16    C7               Heptanes   6.359   3.748   1.122   3.477   2.980   3.679
17   NaN        Me-Cyclo-hexane   4.355   2.515   0.678   2.068   1.985   2.401
18   NaN                Toluene   0.407   0.220   0.061   0.174   0.183   0.208
19    C8                Octanes  10.277   6.901   0.692   2.438   4.092   5.759
20   NaN          Ethyl-benzene   0.146   0.091   0.010   0.032   0.058   0.076
21   NaN       Meta/Para-xylene   0.885   0.553   0.029   0.095   0.333   0.436
22   NaN           Ortho-xylene   0.253   0.158   0.002   0.007   0.091   0.119
23    C9                Nonanes   8.683   6.552   0.280   1.113   3.266   5.160
24   NaN         Tri-Me-benzene   0.496   0.351   0.000   0.000   0.176   0.261
25   C10                Decanes   8.216   6.877   0.108   0.451   2.985   5.233
```

I'd like to replace all the NaN values with the values from the previous row in 'scn' column and then to reindex the dataframe using multiindex on two columns 'scn' and 'cl_name'.

I do it with those two lines of code:

```
df['scn'] = df['scn'].ffill()
df.set_index(['scn', 'cl_name'], inplace=True)
```

The first line with ffil() does what I want replacing NaNs with above values. But after doing set_index() these values are disappearing leaving blank cells.

```
                            lqd_mp  lqd_wp  gas_mp  gas_wp  res_mp  res_wp
scn  cl_name                                                              
C6   Hexanes                 3.398   1.723   2.200   5.835   2.614   2.775
     Me-Cyclo-pentane        1.193   0.591   0.439   1.146   0.707   0.733
     Benzene                 0.037   0.017   0.013   0.030   0.021   0.020
     Cyclo-hexane            1.393   0.690   0.697   1.820   0.944   0.979
C7   Heptanes                6.359   3.748   1.122   3.477   2.980   3.679
     Me-Cyclo-hexane         4.355   2.515   0.678   2.068   1.985   2.401
     Toluene                 0.407   0.220   0.061   0.174   0.183   0.208
C8   Octanes                10.277   6.901   0.692   2.438   4.092   5.759
     Ethyl-benzene           0.146   0.091   0.010   0.032   0.058   0.076
     Meta/Para-xylene        0.885   0.553   0.029   0.095   0.333   0.436
     Ortho-xylene            0.253   0.158   0.002   0.007   0.091   0.119
C9   Nonanes                 8.683   6.552   0.280   1.113   3.266   5.160
     Tri-Me-benzene          0.496   0.351   0.000   0.000   0.176   0.261
C10  Decanes                 8.216   6.877   0.108   0.451   2.985   5.233
```

I'd like no blanks in 'scn' part of the index. What am I doing wrong?
 Thanks

Comment: There are no blanks. That's just how the data is "painted" onto the terminal. If you print `df.index.values` you will see the values safe and sound there.

Comment: as cs95 mentioned , its just the way pandas displays the multiindex,there is nothing that is missing here, however there is an option to display all of them using `with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False): print(df)`

Comment: Thank you guys! Pretty stupid of me to not realise it myself.

Comment: I am reluctant to delete it, it is still a bit of knowledge that can save time for others puzzled by the same "phenomenon". Is there a way to mark it "resolved" or something?

Comment: We can just vote to close it.